# Mustache and brunch.io

Tags: mustache, brunch, hogan.js

I would like to use mustache as a template in a project using brunch. However I don't understand how to integrate https://github.com/mdp/hoganjs-brunch in my workflow. Actually in don't even understand what it's supposed to do !

Any help/suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install --save hoganjs-brunch` as any other plugin.

hoganjs-brunch introduces support of `.hbs` files to compilation part of brunch. Your hbs files will be compiled to javascript.

There is also much more used plugin `handlebars-brunch` which is mustache too, but more supported.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give handlebars a try.